# Create new avd from command line in java

Tags: java, android, cmd, android-virtual-device

I create the method with this:

```
private boolean createAvd(Account account) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        boolean isCreated = true;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        String commandToCreate ="echo no | avdmanager create avd -n "+account.getId()+" -k "+SYSTEM_IMAGE+"";
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new 
        ProcessBuilder("avdmanager.bat "  , commandToCreate );
        processBuilder.directory(new File(PATH_AVD_MANAGER));
        java.util.List<String> list =processBuilder.command();
        for (String string : list) {
            System.out.println("Command : "+ string);
        }
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(process.exitValue() == 0) {
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
    }else {
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream());
        isCreated = false;
    }
    System.out.println("The exit excute value is :"+ process.exitValue());
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        isCreated = false;
    }
    return isCreated;
    }
```

and when I run the code I got this error:

> Command : avdmanager.bat
>   Command : echo no | avdmanager create avd -n 15068894 -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
>   The exit excute value is :255
>   The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>   failed to create the avd

the following command:

```
echo no | avdmanager create avd -n 15068894 -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
```

work normal and create the avd but the method can`t create avd

echo no for the answer of avdmanager question `Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no]`
can anyone tell me what did I miss?

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` is not a shell interpreter. Perhaps this _Stack Overflow_ question will help: [How to execute a PowerShell command from JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957671/how-to-execute-a-powershell-command-from-javafx/56959542#56959542)